# How can I get library DescTools to work on R with ARM Mac M1

Tags: r, arm, desctools

I am running R on Mac with ARM with the following config:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4
```

I get the following error when trying to load library `DescTools`:

```
> install.packages('DescTools', dependencies = TRUE)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1/DescTools_0.99.42.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6049366 bytes (5.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.8 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/4q/q405mpt54ss0hp_4r3c5wx680000gn/T//RtmpCBnNNg/downloaded_packages
> library(DescTools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DescTools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rootSolve’
>
```

Is this terminal and should I revert to R under Intel, or is there some fix?

Comment: The error msg says: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DescTools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rootSolve’"
I'd suggest to believe it and try to install rootSolve by hand.

Comment: This worked - I had to do this for a number of other packages as well. Thanks